# FileMaker Pro 6 Change Language

Tags: filemaker

I work in a Japanese company and my company uses Japanese version of **FileMaker Pro 6**. But I and a few other employees prefer the English version. How do I change the language? Also let me know other possible solutions for this situation.

p.s. Upgrading FMP 6 is not an option for me. I need a reply for FMP 6 only, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow. I suggest you ask at one of the Filemaker forums.

Comment: +1 michael. Look for the original installers and licences or get them on ebay. When you re-install it select English as language. It is one installer for all languages, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I no longer have FileMaker 6 installed, but if you're not finding an obvious preference for the setting, I would guess that it's reading the default language of the OS, and would next look to changing that to English if possible.